# ContentCachingResponseWrapper : How to get application response object (not httpResponse) using ContentCachingResponseWrapper

Tags: spring-mvc, httpresponse

Using Interceptors to validate the requests in Spring Web. 
I've extended HandlerInterceptorAdapter to implement postHandle method. 
I want to check the value inside application response object and accordingly do some action.

I tried IOUtils to get the app response object but getting a "" string.

```
public class XYZInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView)
        throws Exception {

    ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
    ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);

    // need to retrieve application response object

    return;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

After going through many docs, and hands on I figured out that the input stream / output steam can be accessed only once. The response object would already have written output stream somewhere before it reaches postHandler. So output stream is empty in response object of postHandle.

If you wish to access response object in postHandle is to setAttribute for request object with actual response object.